# Junit Tests returning as Unrooted Tests

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I've similar questions asked on this site, but this is a bit of a different scenario than what I have seen.

We have a PC client execute JUnit 4 tests. However, we have a custom test runner that ships the JUnit 4 tests as JUnit 3 tests (using JUnit38ClassRunner) over ethernet to a target system that is running a service that executes JUnit tests using JUnit 3.8. The tests execute as intended, however, when they are returned to the PC client they are marked as Unrooted Tests. Is there a way to organize these tests as "non-unrooted tests"? It is somewhat difficult to sift through the failed results when they are all returned in one group when not using Eclipse. Using JUnit 4 is not an option on the remote system as the target embedded system uses Java 1.4.2, and this is not changing anytime in the near future. We really do not want to have to downgrade to JUnit 3.8 on the PC client side because of the @RunWith annotation, which will take us a little while to figure out how to re-implement.

Any assistance on this is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution for this in Eclipse, but using Ant to manage the junit execution generates xml reports, and I can view the summary in a web page by compiling those reports using the <junitreport> element.